# How to change this prefix trie to return all words that contain similar prefixes

Tags: python, prefix, trie

Hi this is a portion of my code for prefix trie, i trying to get it to return more than just prefix, more explanation at the bottom:

```
class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.isString = False
        self.children = {}


def insertString(word, root):
    currentNode = root
    for char in word:
        if char not in currentNode.children:
            currentNode.children[char] = TrieNode()
        currentNode = currentNode.children[char]
    currentNode.isString = True


def findStrings(prefix, node, results):
    if node.isString:
        results.append(prefix)
    for char in node.children:
        findStrings(prefix + char, node.children[char], results)


def longestPrefix(word, root):
    currentNode = root
    currentPrefix = ''
    for char in word:
        if char not in currentNode.children:
            break
        else:
            currentNode = currentNode.children[char]
            currentPrefix += char
    strings = []
    findStrings(currentPrefix, currentNode, strings)
    return strings
    pass
    # Discussion: Is it dangerous to assume that findStrings actually found a string?
    # Hint: There is an edge case that will break this


wordList = ['aydt', 'coombs', 'schuhmacher', 'claypoole', 'exhume', 'forehands', 'carin', 'plaits', 'alfonsin',
            'hometowns', 'pedestals', 'emad', 'hourly', 'purchaser', 'spogli', 'combativeness', 'henningsen', 'luedke',
            'duchin', 'koglin', 'teason', 'bumpings', 'substantially', 'lamendola', 'cecola', 'henze', 'tutti', 'dills',
            'satirical', 'jetted', 'intertwine', 'predict', 'breezes', 'cyclist', 'ancillary', 'schaumburg', 'viewer',
            "bay's", 'emissions', 'kincheloe', 'trees', 'vipperman', 'exhale', 'ornamental', 'repeated', 'pedestal',
            'pedesta', 'pedest']

root = TrieNode()

for word in wordList:
    insertString(word, root)

allWords = []
findStrings('', root, allWords)
print(allWords)

inputWord = 'co'
print(longestPrefix(inputWord, root))

inputWord = 'pedestals'
print(longestPrefix(inputWord, root))
```

I trying to understand how do i get `print(longestPrefix('pedestals', root))` to return 'pedestals','pedestal','pedesta', 'pedest' and not just pedestals. What am i missing in my code?

Answer (score 0):

> I trying to understand how do i get print(longestPrefix('pedestals',
>   root)) to return 'pedestals','pedestal','pedesta', 'pedest' and not
>   just pedestals.

Since **pedestals** isn't a prefix, this doesn't make sense given the logic of the code -- I would have expected you to wonder why `print(longestPrefix('pedest', root))` didn't return those four results.  I've reworked your code below, turning all your functions into methods since each was taking the object you defined as an argument:

```
class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.isString = False
        self.children = {}

    def insertString(self, word):
        for char in word:
            if char not in self.children:
                self.children[char] = TrieNode()
            self = self.children[char]
        self.isString = True

    def findStrings(self, prefix):
        results = []
        if self.isString:
            results.append(prefix)

        for char in self.children:
            results.extend((self.children[char]).findStrings(prefix + char))

        return results

    def longestPrefix(self, word):
        currentPrefix = ''

        for char in word:
            if char not in self.children:
                break
            else:
                self = self.children[char]
                currentPrefix += char

        return self.findStrings(currentPrefix)

wordList = [
    'aydt', 'coombs', 'schuhmacher', 'claypoole', 'exhume', 'forehands', 'carin', 'plaits', 'alfonsin',
    'hometowns', 'pedestals', 'emad', 'hourly', 'purchaser', 'spogli', 'combativeness', 'henningsen', 'luedke',
    'duchin', 'koglin', 'teason', 'bumpings', 'substantially', 'lamendola', 'cecola', 'henze', 'tutti', 'dills',
    'satirical', 'jetted', 'intertwine', 'predict', 'breezes', 'cyclist', 'ancillary', 'schaumburg', 'viewer',
    "bay's", 'emissions', 'kincheloe', 'trees', 'vipperman', 'exhale', 'ornamental', 'repeated', 'pedestal',
    'pedesta', 'pedest'
]

root = TrieNode()

for word in wordList:
    root.insertString(word)

allWords = root.findStrings('')
print(allWords)

inputWord = 'co'
print(root.longestPrefix(inputWord))

inputWord = 'pedest'
print(root.longestPrefix(inputWord))
```

The last two print statements output:

```
['coombs', 'combativeness']
['pedest', 'pedesta', 'pedestal', 'pedestals']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wordList = ['aydt', 'coombs', 'schuhmacher', 'claypoole', 'exhume', 'forehands', 'carin', 'plaits', 'alfonsin',
            'hometowns', 'pedestals', 'emad', 'hourly', 'purchaser', 'spogli', 'combativeness', 'henningsen', 'luedke',
            'duchin', 'koglin', 'teason', 'bumpings', 'substantially', 'lamendola', 'cecola', 'henze', 'tutti', 'dills',
            'satirical', 'jetted', 'intertwine', 'predict', 'breezes', 'cyclist', 'ancillary', 'schaumburg', 'viewer',
            "bay's", 'emissions', 'kincheloe', 'trees', 'vipperman', 'exhale', 'ornamental', 'repeated', 'pedestal',
            'pedesta', 'pedest']

def findsubstring(fullstring):
    for word in wordList:
        if word in fullstring:
            print (word)

findsubstring("pedestals")
```

output:

```
pedestals
pedestal
pedesta
pedest
```

Comment: `in` seems incorrect - perhaps better to use `startswith`. But this doesn't use OP's trie structure, so it's only an alternative solution for the problem.